# How to encode JMeter response body (JSON) to UTF-8?

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8, jmeter, response

I use a script where I upload a picture to the website and it returns me all the written data in JSON format.
We use this app to recognize name/surname on different documents, we have Russian documents as well.
However, JMeter returns me something like:

```
{
    "message": "recognized",
    "birth_date": "1993",
    "native_name": "\u0406\u042e\u041b\u0414\u0410",
    "patronymic": "\u0410\u0410\u0410\u0410\u0410"
}
```

I tried to change encoding in jmeter.properties and system.properties as well, but it didn`t help. Also I tried to change the encoding via PostProcessor in one string, but no result.

By the way, in Postman I get normal result via 'Beautify' section.

Can anyone help with that issue? Maybe any examples of big PostProcessors, which can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve, if you just need these values in their "text" human-readable representation you can get them using i.e. Groovy's [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)

[image]

If you want to substitute the original response with its unescaped equivalent - here is another Groovy's one-liner:

```
prev.setResponseData(org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(prev.getResponseDataAsString()),'UTF-8')
```

put it into [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)'s "Script" area and it will do the trick for you

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you, it finally works! Need to go deeper in groovy scripting :)